# How do I drop items in collections in rust

Tags: memory-leaks, rust

I have a small crate called [arr](https://github.com/sjep/array) that is specifically designed for large fixed-sized heap arrays (billions of elements could be stored in this). I have a problem though in understanding the proper way to implement `Drop` for this array.

```rust
pub struct Array<T> {
    size: usize,
    ptr: *mut T,
}
```

My original `Drop` looked like this:

```rust
impl<T> Drop for Array<T> {

    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let objsize = std::mem::size_of::<T>();
        let layout = Layout::from_size_align(self.size * objsize, 8).unwrap();

        unsafe {
            dealloc(self.ptr as *mut u8, layout);
        }
    }
}
```

However - this is clearly not right, because if T is a `Drop` then I am leaking memory - a fact which a kindly github member pointed out to me. But how best should I free this memory? Naively I think I could loop through all the elements and call [std::ptr::drop_in_place](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ptr/fn.drop_in_place.html) on them:

```rust
for i in 0..(self.size as isize) {
    std::ptr::drop_in_place(self.ptr.wrapping_offset(i));
}
```

But if the array is a billion `u8`'s isn't this a terrible idea as that would be a billion no-ops? I guess the compiler should be smart enough to do dead-code elision so perhaps I'm falling prey to premature optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `drop_in_place` loop in an if statement checking  [`std::mem::needs_drop::<T>()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.needs_drop.html).

Comment: Wow - thank you. I guess I should have read the APIs more thoroughly!